how do you remove spaces in email addresses using sed?
I have a file with thousands of email addresses with a space inside the email address that shouldn't be there...
(example Aaliyah, Graves: Graves Aaliyah@yahoo.com) as pictured above...
I'd like to know how to remove the space in the email address so that the file reads
(Aaliyah, Graves: GravesAaliyah@yahoo.com) instead as pictured below...

I've been trying for hours to figure it out and I'm defeated. please help!
Edit: Many of these answers were fantastic, thank you everyone!
I'd also like to say hello and again a bit thank you to everyone that provided an answer to this question. I'm frankly amazed that there are so many ways to solve this problem, and as I learn more I plan on returning to this question so that I can continue to appreciate and be astounded by the creativity seen on display here. You are all artists with a keyboard -- well, some of you are mad scientists but that's besides the point. I couldn't upvote anyone's answers as I'm lacking the 15 reputation points that would require, but I just wanted to take a moment to say thank you. I hope to count myself amongst your ranks one day.

Edit the question and add an example of what appears in the file along with the expected result. Use the code blocks so that it is easier to read. Also include what you have tried that didn't work so the same isn't suggested.

The question contains examples as requested.

Note that the transformation you're doing has no guarantee to be right; Graves.Aaliyah@yahoo.com, aaliyah@yahoo.com or anything else might just be as correct. I'm very skeptical of your data set; your transformation only works if you know the space was inserted, and who would go ahead and "break" existing email addresses by inserting spaces? Or is this some large organization, where every employee has FirstnameLastname@domain, and that's a known fact? (and if its a fact, how does it account for people with identical names?)

Marcus, The file was given to my class by my professor. I wont receive extra credit or anything for figuring it out, I'd just really like to know. All the names and emails in the file are completely fictitious. It was just a challenge that he presented. If you can help that would be great. I will append my question to show a screenshot of some of the file.

Please replace the images with plain text. We can't copy/paste images to test a potential solution with.

With perl:
$ perl -pe 's{:\s*\K([^:@]*@)}{$& =~ s/\s//gr}ge' your-question
I have a file with thousands of email addresses with a space
inside the email address that shouldn't be there... (example
'Aaliyah, Graves: GravesAaliyah@yahoo.com'). I'd like to
know how to remove the space in the email address so that
the file reads ('Aaliyah, Graves: GravesAaliyah@yahoo.com')
instead. I've been trying for hours to figure it out and I'm
defeated. please help!

That searches for : followed by optional whitespace which are Kept, and then replaces everything following that (and which doesn't contain other : characters) up to the first occurrence of @ and substitutes it with itself ($&) where all whitespace have been substituded with nothing.

Given your updated input sample, it might be easier to use awk with : as field separator and simply remove all spaces from the second field:
awk -F: 'BEGIN{OFS=": "}{gsub (/ /,"",$2);print}' input.txt


This would not work if the name contains more than one space (any "von" name or similar).

I appreciate your answer userene! I cant wait to talk about the different solutions presented with my teacher tomorrow!

Treating the input as a structured file with :  (colon+space) as the separator between key and value, and newlines as the separator between fields, we may use Miller (mlr) to remove the spaces of each key's value:
$ cat file
Aaliyah, Graves: Graves Aaliyah@yahoo.com
John, von Bumble: von Bumble John@example.com

$ mlr --ps ': ' --fs nl put 'for (k,v in $*) { $[k] = gssub(v, " ", "") }' file
Aaliyah, Graves: GravesAaliyah@yahoo.com
John, von Bumble: vonBumbleJohn@example.com


Treating the input as YAML, we could use Andrey Kislyuk's yq (a wrapper around the jq JSON processor) to apply a global substitution to all values:
$ yq -y 'map_values(gsub(" "; ""))' file
Aaliyah, Graves: GravesAaliyah@yahoo.com
John, von Bumble: vonBumbleJohn@example.com

If using Mike Farah's yq, then replace gsub(" "; "") with sub(" ", "").

This was brilliant, and accounts for names where there is more than one space! Thank you very much.
